# Jquery Form Validation nor working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

Please help me out i am new to asp.net, wanted to create one simple page with form validation.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#Form1").validate({
        rules: {
                UserName: "required"

            },
            messages: {
                UserName: "Enter your firstname"
            }
         });

    });


</script>
```

Login.aspx Page

### Log In

```
<p>
    Please enter your username and password.
    <asp:HyperLink ID="RegisterHyperLink" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">Register</asp:HyperLink> if you don't have an account.

</p>
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <span class="failureNotification">
            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </span>

        <div class="accountInfo">
            <fieldset class="login">
                <legend>Account Information</legend>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Username:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:TextBox>

                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="inline">Keep me logged in</asp:Label>
                </p>

            </fieldset>
            <p class="submitButton">
                <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

Above shown is partial code i have written on my master page.

No error displayed, but unfortunately script is not working.

Comment: show console output. are you sure you want to use http on the library source?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: this code is correct, you could show html fragment

Comment: you must remember that validation result is shown when the form does summit or call the method valid() explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Didn't knew that script should be as per the asp:login control.

"<%= ((TextBox)LoginUser.FindControl("UserName")).UniqueID %>"

Sorry guys, before i missed my HTML code :(